Почему в слове мутаген следует писать букву А?
Я думала, что здесь будет крайне уместна буква О в качестве соединительной гласной. Если посмотреть, в интернете это обосновывают корнем мутА. Но буквально там же пишут, что в слове мутация корень мут.Оно и понятно, что мут, ведь есть слово мутирование, например. Так почему же в слове мутаген корнем вдруг становится мутА, так ещё и нет привычной красивой соединительной гласной О. То, что слово мутаген и мутация должны быть однокоренными, тоже вполне понятно.
Можно, кстати, ещё предположить, что там беглая гласная в корне. Но разве она может вот так вот в конце корня стоять? Да даже если так, то почему она появляется только в слове мутаген и в производных от него словах? Будто бы здесь как нигде должна стоять соединительная О.
Объясните, пожалуйста, мне это слово не даёт спокойно спать по ночам..

Мутация (от лат. mutatio — изменение, перемена), мutato (лат.) — мутировать.
В русском языке много таких пар: провоцировать — провокация, деградировать — деградация, дискриминировать — дискриминация. В глаголе выделяется суффикс -ирова, а в существительном — суффикс -ациj.
Аналогично: мут/ирова/ть —  мут/Ация.
МутА/генез (от мутация и греч. γένεσις – рождение, происхождение).  Здесь усечение основы на -ция и присоединение иноязычного элемента -генез.
Соответственно: мутА/ген. Мутагены — химические и физические факторы, вызывающие наследственные изменения — мутации.
Таким образом, формант А — это часть суффикса ациj,  а с другой стороны — соответствие латинским словам: mutatio, mutato.

В РЯ сложно найти прямо-аналогичный пример. Может вы и правы, что надо -о- ставить.
Вот тут кое-какая инфа, но все как-то мимо кассы.
Например, есть слова:
Авиабаза    // Авиа - не корень
Минералогия // Усечение корня от минералология
Генеалогия  // Тут вообще корень генеалогия (тихонов)
Умалишение  // Падежное окончание
Океанавт    // Усечение корня океан
Метагенез   // Мета не корень
Диагенез    // Может это? Хотя нет, диа - приставка, означающая движение сквозь

Но все они как-то не туда

Но зато в РЯ можно найти правильное написание для этого примера: Русский орфографический словарь
мутаген, -а.   Очень рекомендую)   https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=мутаген&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71
